# Youtube API json request is not returning items with certain videos

Tags: jquery, json, video, youtube

I can not afford this issue. I have been modifying, changing, reprogramming scripts, but I can not get items trough **Youtube JSON API** with videos that I want.

Videos are HIDDEN, not private, not public, just HIDDEN.

When I make a request to the api with my videos, the response is:

```
jQuery19104313711607975359_1385141694160({"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"updated":"2013-11-22T17:32:03.121Z","totalItems":0,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":25}});
```

And when I make the request with anyother video from youtube, the response:

```
jQuery19104339515392212546_1385141117118({"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"updated":"2013-11-22T17:22:26.071Z","totalItems":1,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":25,"items":[{"id":"LzmkfS0q12o","uploaded":"2012-08-03T13:51:11.000Z","updated":"2013-11-21T17:14:32.000Z","uploader":"danflexofficial","category":"Music","title":"Zedd - Spectrum(Ft. Matthew Koma) FL Studio Remake + FLP","description":"Soundcloud : http://soundcloud.com/daniel-xv -Song starts at 1:13 -My remake of Zedd's - Spectrum. The FLP ; You must like my page in order to download the ...","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LzmkfS0q12o/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LzmkfS0q12o/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzmkfS0q12o&feature=youtube_gdata_player"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/LzmkfS0q12o?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"},"duration":382,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.8360834,"likeCount":"872","ratingCount":909,"viewCount":67858,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":379,"status":{"value":"restricted","reason":"limitedSyndication"},"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"denied"}}]}});
```

What I could see, is that the object "items" is null and does not exists in my videos, why?

I am using this plugin: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/

We have tried with another account, another video, set to hidden, and everything works fine. But when we upload oner of my videos to another channel, and set to Hidden, then the response went wrong.

I do not know if it is a problem about certain videos (they are all from the same camera, and the same event, divided in parts, diferents videos) or the channel instead.

I do not know, any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: *"What I could see, is that the object "items" is null and does not exists in my videos, why?"* because there are no items to display. totlaItems is 0.

Comment: Are you sur ethe fact that the videos are hidden has anything to do with this? have you tried making them visible on your account just as a test to see if they show up? have you given the api enough time to update? (i recall certain parts of the api only updating once every 30 min)

Comment: Thats a good hint Kevin, the time. I will try with that and see what happens. I will do all the tests again, but I was sure that I had tried all the possibilities. Let me check all videos again.

Comment: Everything is true. The API last 30 minutes to refresh video statuses, and HIDDEN videos are not possible to be seen trough the API, is there any way to show HIDDEN videos trough YOutube DAta API?